# solve it if you can

Tags: number-sequence

> n = 11,
>   j = 1,
>   s = 9,
>   m = ?

If you solve it you are a genius.

Answer (score 5):

Those are...

> SI units: Newtons, joules, seconds and meters.

So...

> $$N = \frac{kg \times m}{s^2}$$
> $$11 = \frac{kg \times m}{81}$$
> $$891 = kg \times m$$
> $$J = \frac{kg \times m^2}{s^2}$$
> $$1 = \frac{kg \times m^2}{81}$$
> $$81 = kg \times m^2$$
> $$\frac{891}{81} = \frac{kg \times m}{kg \times m^2}$$
> $$11 = \frac{1}{m}$$
> $$m = \frac{1}{11}$$